# How to get Instagram custom square size image other than thumbnail

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've been using the below code to get the square size images of 320x320 square size images using the instagram API returned images.

> $image = $vm['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
>
> $image = str_replace('s150x150/', 's320x320/', $image);

And looks like instagram is now not returining those square size images. Have any one encounter such problems while fetching the instgram images using instagram API? or is there any way to get the thumbnail size images other than 150x150?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple as substituting the dimensions in the URL. This technique seemed to work in the past and still works for some images, but doesn't seem to work for every image now.

If you look at the API response listing all the available image sizes, you'll notice that they all have different hashes in them.

Just use the actual URLs returned by the API for each size of the photo.